# problems with repel in fviz_cluster in factoextra package in R

Tags: r, factoextra

I've created very simple clusters in iris:

```
library(factoextra)

iris.kmeans<-kmeans(iris[, c(1,2)], centers=3)

fviz_cluster(iris.kmeans, data=iris[,c(1,2)])
```

which produces the cluster plot that you'd expect.  However, when I put repel=T in it:

```
fviz_cluster(iris.kmeans, data=iris[,c(1,2)], repel = T)
```

I get the error

> Error in replace_null(unclass(data), label = "a", angle = 0) :  could
> not find function "replace_null"

I've never seen this before!  Any ideas?

(the dataset I'm actually doing this with has a lot of row names that are not integers, and the plots are really overwhelming).

I've tried going back to previous code where this worked, and I'm pretty sure this is identical to what I used to do.

Comment: Have you tried running `library(ggrepel)` before running your example? I am not able to reproduce your error, but I perhaps the function isn't available because it's not installed?

Comment: Yes I did do that and no luck.